# How to prevent the result of Servlets from being cached?

Tags: java, caching, servlets

How can I stop caching of pages in browser using Servlets?

I want that session should expire if I press back button of browser when i am logged in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict user from the previous page after signout.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/restrict-user-from-the-previous-page-after-signout)

Answer (score 10):

To permanently disable cache.

```
  // Set to expire far in the past.
  response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");

  // Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

  // Set IE extended HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (use addHeader).
  response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");

  // Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Clearing the client cache would not  expire session immediately,but clears session cookies in the browser. To make the session expire immediately, you need to explicitly specify in server side jsp or servlet.

```
// use session invalidate
session.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get a [HttpServletResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) (implementation) object for the request you can send HTTP headers that will encourage browsers not to cache the content you send them.

```
HttpServletResponse response; // You'll need to initialize this properly

response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
```

See the documentation for [HttpServletResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html). In case you need to read up on cache control headers in HTTP, [check this out](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html).

Comment: Are all the above lines required or any one of the `setHeader()` is sufficient?

Comment: @Alpine Depends on the browser. See the link I just added regarding cache control headers. These are just examples.

Comment: R.Younce : Thanks..but i am still getting a problem. after logging in if i press back & then forward the session is still on

Comment: @Prashant You said you wanted to avoid caching. What exactly are you trying to expire?

Comment: `response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");` why do we use `-1`

Comment: @Mike So that it is immediately expired.