# Why isn't my filter invoked on second time an URL is requested?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

When I enter the url through the browser for the first time, my servlet filter is hit. For example, `appPages/Nav.xhtml?id=1` pasted first time in the browser does refresh the page. 
Now, when i change the query string to `appPages/Nav.xhtml?id=2` also refreshes the page.

But the third time I enter `appPages/Nav.xhtml?id=1` it still remembers the old stage and my filter is never called. In my web.xml I have configured the filter as

```
<filter>
    <display-name>SearchParamsFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>SearchParams</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.acme.filter.SearchParams</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>SearchParams</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/appPages/Nav.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Why is it remembering the old state? This only happens when I enter the url in the same tab same window again. But a reload works fine.

UPDATE: It works fine on Chrome but not on IE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by client-side caching. Make sure you disable caching by setting the appropriate response headers in your servlets and/or filters. See the following answers for detailed instructions:

[How to prevent the result of Servlets from being cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139785/how-to-prevent-the-result-of-servlets-from-being-cached)

[Java servlet how to disable caching of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976624/java-servlet-how-to-disable-caching-of-page)