# java/jsf redirect page

Tags: java, jsf

when i opend my login page and i have connected with my email and password and when i diconnected page i am going to login page its gud upto here and when i press back button in the browser i am going to main page again.

I have deleted sessions by using session.invalidate(),but iam not able to rediect the page to login.

Comment: Do you see the main page also after refreshing the page? What kind of authentication do you use: container-based or application-based?

Comment: yes ,even when i refresh the page i am going to my main page.

Comment: i am using application based authentification

Comment: @ MattHandy:yes ,even when i refresh the page i am going to my main page.
 
i am using application based authentification

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict user from the previous page after signout.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/restrict-user-from-the-previous-page-after-signout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your page is cached.

Create a filter that will set following headers to the response

```
HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Back Button** brings HTML pages from browser cache. You do not have a control over it. But make sure that your authentication management does not let use the functionality that requires authenticated user.

You may, however set "no-cache" is header. But, I *strongly discourage* it. see how:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
```