# Does not go to the previous page when logout

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp project and I use session to user authority. I have used

```
session.invalidate();
```

in the logout page.

After logout, when I press the back button, it shows the previous page.
I don't want it to do this.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Restrict user from accessing the previous page after signout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/restrict-user-from-accessing-the-previous-page-after-signout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cache on the html to expire on you logout confirmation page. The details for the tags can be had from here.

> http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm