# How to disable browser back button after logout in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict user from accessing the previous page after signout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/restrict-user-from-accessing-the-previous-page-after-signout)

Am developing a JSP application in netbeans 6.5.1. I need to disable browser back button after login as well as log off. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing you can do in JSP to directly influence that browser's back button.  Your JSP markup/code is all evaluated server-side as part of generating the response that is set to the client.

That said, you can add the following JavaScript to the `<head>` section of the post-logoff page to accomplish roughly the desired effect:

```
<script>
    history.forward();
</script>
```

Source:  http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/574062.html

More generally, however, there's nothing you can do to prevent a determined user from finding a previously visited URL in their history and pointing their browser to it after logging out.  Instead your session-management code needs to be robust enough to know that it should not service a request for a stale URL if the user no longer holds a valid session.

Or, if what you're really trying to do is prevent the browser from displaying a cached version of a post-login page after a user has logged out, you can accomplish that (in most browsers) by setting an HTTP [Cache-Control](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) header with a value of `no-cache` on all of your post-login pages.

Comment: Thank you... Will try now and ping you back.