# After logout stay on same page when user clicks on back button

Tags: java, session, logout, back-button

After logout the user is directed to login page. Now, if user clicks on back button it should stay on login page itself. How can I make it possible by using code in java? I have used Servlet Filter... Tried invalidating session.I have even tried clearing cache(Expires, Cache-Control, Pragma).But got no success yet. Or maybe I’m using this in wrong way. Please guide me the correct way.

Comment: invalidating the session should work fine. Can you show us some code so we can help you more?

Comment: Checkout the link below, have answered it already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420941/how-handle-browser-back-button-in-spring-mvc/31217043#31217043

Answer (score 0):

The below posts might give you an idea about how to handle such cases

- [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)
- [How to disable browser back button after logout in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949801/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-after-logout-in-jsp)