# Browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, back-button

I’m using following line of code to disable the browser back button problem after logout.

```
function LogoutOnClick() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```

But, there is one problem with this code, supposing I’ve three page first is login page(`login.cshtml`) and second successfully logged in page(`home.cshtml`) and third page is about page (`about.cshtml`),

now I do login then it will redirect me on `home.cshtml` page now that I move on the third page `about.cshtml` and after that I do logout from `about.cshtml` page, it redirects me on `login.cshtml` page.

And now if I `clicked on browser back button` then redirects me on `about.cshtml` page again but there user couldn’t change or add anything.

So let me know is there any appropriate code or method to resolved this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to disable browser caching of pages that are only visible when logged in to prevent users from going back to pages they had when they were logged in, after they've logged out. Then you won't need to worry about disabling the back button. If they try access a page that requires them to be logged in, you'll redirect them to the login page.

Comment: How can I disable Caching of pages using javascript or jquery?

Comment: @user1273915 What are you using to produce the pages? Whatever does, needs to add these meta tags in the `<head>` tag: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1" />`

Answer (score 4):

To disable the back browser button learn more : [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

I think that this code will can help you :

```
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

EDIT : For disable after a logout check this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949801/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-after-logout-in-jsp)

Comment: Above code stop back button for all time but i want to stop back button only in case of logout.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, that disabling the back-button in the browser is what you want, or not what you should want! From a security point of view, you should try to destroy the session. And you should proof the permissions at every request of the page.

Think about, what you want to archive ;-)

Comment: then I do not understand why you want to disable the back-button?

Comment: because after logout when I click on back button it will move in the Admin menu if I was travers all the pages in the AdminPanel.

Comment: as Bernhard said, disable browser caching and make sure, that you proof the session-permissions on every request...