# Browser Back button to previous page

Tags: php, jquery

How to navigate the webpage to previous pages when the browser's BACK button is click.

The current status I having is when I at "product page" redirect to "product detail page".

I click on browser's back button it redirect me to home page.

Did have any solution where the browser's back button able to navigate to the previous page

Comment: i think you have header redirection check it first

Comment: @user790454 Can give some example?

Comment: check your code in which you are redirecting. check there if any redirection code like in php `header('Location:home.php')` or in javascript `location.href='home.php'` like this

Comment: @user790454 Yes, but I put it on particular button and is not the back button from browser.

Comment: may be theres a redirection if not logged in or something like that, you have to show your code,without that we cant tell you anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache" /> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1" />
```

Try adding these codes to your page and see.

Something similar with this. [Browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405199/browser-back-button)