# Disabling back button in JSP after logging in?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

(Disabling back button in JSP after logging in?)

What does this code mean? Anyone pls explain this following code.Because, I never studied about this 'response.setHeader' method.

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader ("Expires", "0"); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

or any other methods are available for disabling back button in JSP after Logging in?

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) For ```response.setHeader()```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the user to go back then try this small script.

```
<script>
    history.forward();
</script>
```

Put this code into the `<head>` element of your page and try to go back. For more details click on following link...

[How to disable browser back button after logout in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949801/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-after-logout-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

This code sets response headers.
Headers is http feature, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
This code just works this in Java.

Comment: Thank u, Any other methods are available for disabling back button in JSP? I urgently need it.Pls, help me out...

Comment: **disabling back button in JSP** - I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: 1. JSP absolutely cannot do this, browser history is clien code task.

Comment: After logging in into some page, for example, like banking or any other transactions, u can't go back to the previous page. For disabling that back button property I am asking..

Comment: That is why, I am asking any other methods are available or not. Can we do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript, for example by asking user not to go away from the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost."; };
```