# JSF authentication logout

Tags: jsf, authentication, glassfish, logout, jaas

I know that this question seems to be answered by a lot of other threads, but I can't find a solution with JSF 2.0 with Glassfish 3.0.1 for logout an user.
I tried either with a BASIC authentication and FORM authentication using j_security_check as action.
But for the logout method I can't find any of them that works.

I tried using a servlet with session.invalidate(), i used a managed bean tring to invalide the session, but nothing happened. I also tried with j_security_logout without success.

Does someone know what I can do for logout an user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `session.invalidate()` should work.

Your problem is probably that you used the browser back button to view a restricted page to test if logout really succeeded, but that page was *actually* served from the browser cache instead of straight from the webserver over a real HTTP connection.

In that case, you need to instruct the webbrowser to **not** cache the restricted pages. This way the browser will always request the page straight from the webserver. You can do this with help of a [Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). You can find an example in this question: [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/restrict-user-from-accessing-the-previous-page-after-signout)