# How implement a login filter in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, authentication, authorization, servlet-filters

I would like to block the access of some page even if the user knows the url of some pages.
For example, `/localhost:8080/user/home.xhtml` (need to do the login first) if not logged then redirect to `/index.xhtml`.

How do that in JSF ? I read in the Google that's needed a filter, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to implement the [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) class, do the desired job in `doFilter()` method and map it on an URL pattern covering the restricted pages, `/user/*` maybe? Inside the `doFilter()` you should check the presence of the logged-in user in the session somehow. Further you also need to take JSF ajax and resource requests into account. JSF ajax requests require a special XML response to let JavaScript perform a redirect. JSF resource requests need to be skipped otherwise your login page won't have any CSS/JS/images anymore.

Assuming that you've a `/login.xhtml` page which stores the logged-in user in a JSF managed bean via `externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user)`, then you could get it via `session.getAttribute("user")` the usual way like below:

```
@WebFilter("/user/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String AJAX_REDIRECT_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        + "<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

        boolean loggedIn = (session != null) && (session.getAttribute("user") != null);
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL);
        boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER + "/");
        boolean ajaxRequest = "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"));

        if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
            if (!resourceRequest) { // Prevent browser from caching restricted resources. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4194207/157882
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
            }

            chain.doFilter(request, response); // So, just continue request.
        }
        else if (ajaxRequest) {
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().printf(AJAX_REDIRECT_XML, loginURL); // So, return special XML response instructing JSF ajax to send a redirect.
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(loginURL); // So, just perform standard synchronous redirect.
        }
    }


    // You need to override init() and destroy() as well, but they can be kept empty.
}
```

Additionally, the filter also disabled browser cache on secured page, so the browser back button won't show up them anymore.

In case you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), above code could be reduced as below:

```
@WebFilter("/user/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

        boolean loggedIn = (session != null) && (session.getAttribute("user") != null);
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL);
        boolean resourceRequest = Servlets.isFacesResourceRequest(request);

        if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
            if (!resourceRequest) { // Prevent browser from caching restricted resources. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4194207/157882
                Servlets.setNoCacheHeaders(response);
            }

            chain.doFilter(request, response); // So, just continue request.
        }
        else {
            Servlets.facesRedirect(request, response, loginURL);
        }
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlet Filters wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)
- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)
- [Using JSF 2.0 / Facelets, is there a way to attach a global listener to all AJAX calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305144/using-jsf-2-0-facelets-is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-global-listener-to-all-ajax/)
- [Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application)
- [JSF: How control access and rights in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516349/jsf-how-control-access-and-rights-in-jsf)

Comment: instead of using getAttribute("auth"), could you use @ManagedProperty(value="#{auth}")
 private Auth auth;

Comment: @Jake: Wrong. `@ManagedProperty` works in a `@ManagedBean` only, not in a `@WebFilter`.

Comment: @Jake: If you're using CDI's `@Named` instead, then you can use `@Inject` to inject it in both a `@ManagedBean` (or just another `@Named`) and a `@WebFilter`.

Comment: @BalusC: Would we have to worry about thread safety in this technique?

Comment: @BalusC If filter is mapped to `/user/*` and login page is located at `/login.xhtml` I suppose that login requests won't be captured. Login page should be located at `/user/login.xhtml` but then I ask myself: why do we need to protect the login page?

Comment: @BalusC same argument applies to resource requests.

Comment: Hello @BalusC can you more clear about what AJAX_REDIRECT_XML it's and share some doc if you have? thank for great work you do.

Comment: @FarshiDNaqizadeh: It's defined as a constant in the AuthorizationFilter code snippet. Just Ctrl+F it if you cannot see it.

Comment: @BalusC ops, found with your help, sorry , but can you explain what it is?

Comment: @FarshiDNaqizadeh: It's explained in the 1st paragraph: *"JSF ajax requests require a special XML response to let JavaScript perform a redirect."*.

Answer (score 2):

While it's of course legitimate to use a simple Servlet filter, there are alternatives like

- [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
- [Java EE Security](https://javaee.github.io/security-spec/)
- [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/)