# JSF 2.0 - Checking & redirecting if the user is not logged in

Tags: jsf-2

I have implemented a servlet filter that checks whether the user is logged in and redirects the user to the login page if they are not. The reason I am doing this check as a filter is that the login page exists in an another webapp which I cannot seem to redirect to using web.xml's FROM auth-method to redirect to a page that's in a different webapp with a different context root (note, I am using weblogic 11g).

The problem I am experiencing is that when I have an ajaxified component, like a button, the servlet filter is not able to redirect the user. i.e. they wind up right back on the page that they were on.

Is there a different way I should be doing this logged-in check?

Comment: Would a phase listener be more appropriate?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305144/using-jsf-2-0-facelets-is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-global-listener-to-all-ajax/9311920#9311920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-implemented the servlet filter as a JSF 2.0 Phase Listener that runs before the RESTORE_VIEW phase. By moving the logic into a Phase Listener, I was able to take advantage of JSF's ability to handle redirects for an AJAX request. Basically JSF 2.0 will create the proper AJAX response to cause a redirect on the client side. To be clear, this mechanism is able to do a redirect for AJAX and non-AJAX requests if the user is not logged in.

Specifically, it will send back the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<partial-response>
  <redirect url="/contextpath/faces/ajax/redirecttarget.xhtml">
  </redirect>
</partial-response>"
```

Code for the phase listener:

```
public PhaseId getPhaseId() 
{
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) 
{
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ec.getSession(false);

    if (session==null || session.getAttribute(IS_LOGGED_IN_INDICATOR) == null) 
    {
        try
        {
            ec.redirect(LOGIN_PAGE_URL);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // log exception...
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that a PhaseListener doesn't kick in on non-JSF requests. So if you happen to have secured non-JSF resources as well, it won't be checked. You'd need to duplicate the job in the filter, or to do it entirely in the filter.