# Why is Phase Listener-based JSF redirect not working for AJAX requests when session has timed-out?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF Phase Listerner that checks to see if the user is logged in, and if not, redirects them to the login page. This is working fine for non-ajax requests. However, if the user is on a page, in my case, one that has a primefaces data table, and clicks on a button that invokes an ajax request -- but their session has timed out -- the code gets executed that issues the redirect (using `ExternalContext#redirect`), however the user is not navigated to the login page.

Any idea why this is not working?

Here is my phase listener:

```
private static final String IS_LOGGED_IN_INDICATOR = "loggedIn";
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "/login.jsp";

public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}

public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ec.getSession(false);

    if (session==null || session.getAttribute(IS_LOGGED_IN_INDICATOR) == null) {
       try {
            ec.redirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
       }
       catch(IOException e) {
           // log exception...
       }            
    }
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    // no-op
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed because the ajax context is trying to obtain the render kit from the view root, while there is no view root at all. It has not been restored at that point yet. This resulted in  a `NullPointerException` in `PartialViewContext#createPartialResponseWriter()`. This exception is in turn not been thrown, but instead been put in an ajax exception queue which is supposed to be handled by a custom `ExceptionHandler`. You apparently don't have any one. This exception is visible if you create/use such one like the [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) (see also [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html) for more detail).

To fix the particular problem, do the job in `afterPhase()` instead. The view root is then fully restored and the ajax context can obtain the render kit from it in order to write a specialized XML response which instructs the JSF ajax engine in JavaScript to change the window location. Without ajax, a render kit was not necessary as a redirect is basically just a matter of setting a response header.

Whether the particular `NullPointerException` is in turn a bug in Mojarra or not is a different question which can better be posted in flavor of an issue report at their own issue tracker.

Answer (score -1):

this is because you have to send a special response in XML for Ajax request in order to do redirect  (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954319/jsf-2-response-sendredirect-is-not-working)) , I have implemented this in a Filter like this..

```
// Check if it's an Ajax Request 
if ("partial/ajax".equals(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
      //redirect 
      response.setContentType("text/xml");
      response.getWriter()
           .append("<?xml version=  \"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
           .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>",url);
```

you should port this to your Phase Listener.

Comment: The answer you reference says that I DO NOT have to do a special response if I am in the JSF Context: "If the ajax request is initiated by JSF itself (e.g. <f:ajax> and so on) and the Java code is running inside the JSF context, then you should be using ExternalContext#redirect() instead. This autodetects if the current request is an ajax request and will return a special XML response which tells the JSF ajax engine to change the location of the window". To sum up, the answer states that using ExternalContext#redirect should create the proper AJAX response to do the redirect.

Comment: True it is, I had overlooked the fact that you are not using a Filter.. just out of curiosity why are you using a PhaseL istener instead of a normal servlet listener?

BTW do you get any errors in your trace? I have seen some post's with a bug in primefaces regarding this issue...[like this one..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572700/failing-to-redirect-from-jsf-phaselistener)

Comment: I had used a filter but moved it to a phase listener to take advantage of JSF's ability to do the redirect for both AJAX and non-AJAX requests. A servlet filter would have worked if I had also added the code you referenced to handle AJAX requests.