# JSF does not load css file, error message: "The resource from this URL is not text"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

This is my JSF file header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>#{txt.TXT_TITLE_LOGIN}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico"></link>
    <script src="./scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</h:head>
<body...
```

When I opent the page, styles are not loaded, looks very ugly, and Firebug shows this:

```
<link href="scripts/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    The resource from this URL is not text: http://localhost:8080/EWC/scripts/styles.css
</link>
```

... but the file is there, at the location /EWC/scripts.

When I open some other page with very same header all is ok. Then I go back to this page and it is ok too. But it happens again when this page is loaded first after clean browser cash.

What went wrong?

Comment: Are you able to hit the URL http://localhost:8080/EWC/scripts/styles.css on browser and see the content ? What are the response headers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.
Seams like the problem was conntected to [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/jsf-redirect-isnt-working-when-button-submitted).

The following code did not catch `css` file requests, so they were forwarded to Login page via `gotoLogin()` (in case user is not logged in).

```
if( requestURI.startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) )
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
else
    gotoLogin(null, request, response);
    return;
```

I have added

```
if( requestURI.endsWith("css") )
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
```

...and it works.

As BalusC said, I hould have used `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>` instead of `<link>`, `<script>` and `<img>` in the header, and this would never happen.

Comment: You should have used `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>` instead of `<link>`, `<script>` and `<img>`.