# Page not redirect after session expire

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, primefaces, omnifaces

From the previous forums and information from internet I found out that the only logical solution to be redirected to login.xhtml or login page when the session expires is using OmniFaces.

After using omnifaces, I am able to be directed login.xhtml when session expires. Unfortunately, when `ajax=true` at primefaces I am not able to directed to login.xhtml when session expires. I think the problem comes with primefaces. Because, when I use pure Jsf such like `h:commandButton` and when `ajax=true`, I can be directed to login.xhtml when session expires. But it does not work when I use primefaces when `ajax=true`. You can understand what I meant more clear below :

```html
<!-- It can be directed to login.xhtm after session expire -->
<h:commandButton value="throw SQL exception on ajax request"
    action="#{kdsHome.openCandidateAtmSelectPanelListener}">
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>

<!-- It can't be directed to login -->
<p:commandButton value="throw SQL exception on ajax request"
    action="#{kdsHome.openCandidateAtmSelectPanelListener}"
    update="@form">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: *From the previous forums and information from internet I found out that the only logical solution to be redirected to login.xhtml or login page when the session expires is using OmniFaces.* This is **plain wrong**. You can do this in a Filter **since JSF 1.x**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/authorization-redirect-on-session-expiration-does-not-work-on-submitting-a-jsf-f)

Comment: Thank you for using OmniFaces, but I just want to mention that the OmniFaces `FacesExceptionFilter` and `FullAjaxExceptionFilter` are not invoked at all when you do manually a `response.sendRedirect()` in your authentication filter. In other words, they have nothing to do with the concrete problem.

Comment: Luiggi then please tell me how to do it in Filter. I searched many forums and I could not find any detailed info where I can do it in Filter. It does not work with primefaces. Could you please englighten me ?

Comment: BalusC please look at the link where you cansee you can do it with FullAjaxExceptionFilter. It's Omnifaces  : – http://snapshot-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Comment: Could anyone be kind and provide a link or info where I can handle view exceptin handling and redirect to login page when session timeouts at primefaces? Cheers

Comment: I've already posted that link in my 1st comment (sorry for late response, stack exchange comment reply notifier doesn't work properly since a day or two).