# JSF 2.0 Multiple requests generated per page

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have implemented a Filter for checking if a user is logged in or not by checking the session for a `@SessionScoped` bean. When I started testing it, I however, noticed that whenever I accessed one of my pages the Filter would be invoked multiple times.

I have figured out that I needed to ignore AJAX requests which reduced the number of times my filter would be invoked but the number of requests triggered each time I loaded the page was still more than one.

By trial and error, I have figured out that the requests would be generated by the following XHTML tags (both embedded in the `<h:body>` tag):

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="styles/userbar.css" target="head"/>
<o:commandScript name="updateMessages" render="custom_messages"/>
```

The second tag being part of OmniFaces library.

Any ideas why I get multiple requests or maybe if there is a way to ignore the requests generated by these tags?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if you mapped the filter on a generic URL pattern like `@WebFilter("/*")`, or directly on the faces servlet like `@WebFilter(servletNames="facesServlet")`. The requests you're referring to are just coming from (auto-included) CSS/JS/image resources. If you track the browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor (press F12, *Network*) or debug the request URI in filter, then that should have become clear quickly.

As to covering JSF resource requests, if changing the filter to listen on a more specific URL pattern like `@WebFilter("/app/*")` is not possible for some reason, then you'd need to add an additional check on the request URI. Given that you're using OmniFaces, you can use the [`Servlets` utility class](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Servlets) to check in a filter if the current request is a JSF ajax request or a JSF resource request:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class YourFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (Servlets.isFacesAjaxRequest(request) || Servlets.isFacesResourceRequest(request)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/authorization-redirect-on-session-expiration-does-not-work-on-submitting-a-jsf-f/) (contains a "plain vanilla" Servlet example for the case you aren't using OmniFaces)

Comment: Thank you very much! Checking if the request is a resource request fixed the issue!