# Redirect to same page from webfilter independent from called URL

Tags: jsf, redirect, servlet-filters

I've build a login Webfilter, that redirects to the loginpage if the session is not authenticated.

My Problem is, that the redirection redirects to a page within the same folder on the Webserver which fails when the called page is not in the root folder.

The webfilter redirects to "./login.jsf"
Example:
If I call "www.application.ch/App" it works and I get redirected to "www.application.ch/App/login.jsf"

But when I call "www.application.ch/App/pages/page.jsf" it redirects me to "www.application.ch/App/pages/login.jsf"

Ofcourse I could just set the redirect to "../login.jsf" but then it doesnt work when the root is called.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to a domain-relative URL. In other words, always start the redirect URL with `/`, including the context path. If your actual concern is the dynamicness of the context path `/App`, just obtain it programmatically by `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf");
```

Do note that this was already covered by the [filter example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582031) I gave you in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647761).

Comment: Now I have the same problems in JSFs. I've tried to redirect with this statement "#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/user.jsf" but then the application name vanishes from the path