# JSF 2; ajax; redirect from Filter when session is expired causes client browser not to update the page

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, servlet-filters

This question is very similar to this one: [Using JSF 2.0 / Facelets, is there a way to attach a global listener to all AJAX calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305144/using-jsf-2-0-facelets-is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-global-listener-to-all-ajax/9311920#9311920)
But the solution is not working for me. I am missing something.

The problem is:
When session is expired and I click some ajax links/buttons and send redirect (from `Filter`) the browser <del>doesn't update the page</del> *receive the last non-AJAX requested page*.

What I have is:

1. JSF 2.1 on WebSphere (I also use Richfaces 4.2.0)
2. I use AJAX (except the first request after login)
3. I use `@ManagedBean(name = "user") @SessionScoped UserBean` with field `User user` (which in turn is EJB Entity class for users access management)
4. I use OmniFaces classes to perform `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` (And it works fine without my Filter, thanks to BalusC)
5. I use `javax.servlet.Filter` maped to `@WebFilter("*.xhtml")` to manage access to resources and login check. `doFilter()` function snippet:

   ```java
   ....
   if (user == null) { // if user is not logged in
        redirectToLogin(req, res);
   }
   ```

   And there is `redirectToLogin()` function in the same Filter class (thanks again to BalusC (= ):

   ```java
   private static final String FACES_REDIRECT_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
       + "<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>";

   protected void redirectToLogin(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException {
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

       if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
           res.setContentType("text/xml");
           res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           res.getWriter().printf(FACES_REDIRECT_XML, request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
       } else {
           String url = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";
           HttpServletResponse resHttp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
           resHttp.sendRedirect(url);
       }
   }
   ```

When session is expired and I click some ajax links/buttons (ViewExpiredException occurs). I can see in debug that string `res.getWriter().printf(FACES_REDIRECT_XML, request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");` executes. And I can also see HTTP REDIRECT request and response with my <del>login.xhtml</del> (**that is not login page, that is old page from which the last non-AJAX request was made!**) page in Firebug, <del>but browser doesn't update the view</del>.

Can I somehow detect that the ViewExpiredException occurs in Filter (outside FacesContext) and pass control to FullAjaxExceptionHandler? (btw if it is possible then I don't need ajaxExceptionHandler any more for ViewExpiredException, right?)
What is the reason why the browser page is not updating?

As I mentioned in the top of post I read and follow the guidelines the related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305144/using-jsf-2-0-facelets-is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-global-listener-to-all-ajax/9311920#9311920), but I missed something or misunderstand. What could it be?

Thanks.

---

**Update: the HTML code I receive is old HTML-page returned on the last non-AJAX request!** So the thing is that the FacesServlet doesn't send my login.xhtml to client's browser.

**Update2:** I've found out that the page I receive from FasesServlet is the last non-AJAX requested page (in my case it is the first view I see after successful login). (BTW the browser still doesn't update page and there is XML-parsing error which is caused by this line: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >`)

---

**Update3: web.xml:**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>       


    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/loginViewExpired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: *"And I can also see HTTP REDIRECT request and response with my login.xhtml page in Firebug"* Is this a HTTP 200 GET request? The whole `login.xhtml` HTML output is in the "Response" tab? Or do you see raw JSF source code? What URL pattern is your `FacesServlet` mapped on? The code in filter assumes it to be `*.xhtml`.

Comment: 1)My Faces Servlet is mapped on *.xhtml. 2) Yes, it is HTTP 200 GET Request and in Response I could see processed HTML code

Comment: @BalusC And what if I call `chain.doFilter(req, res);` in my `Filter` and then somehow process `ViewExpiredException` in `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` on `RESTORE_VIEW` phase? Is it possible?

Comment: So, your logins are handled by a 3rd party framework which isn't JSF ajax aware and it seems to have a builtin "remember me" functionality?

Comment: I do not use 3rd party frameworks (I believe so =) where such 3rd party frameworks can be attached?). I implement login with my UserBean and EJB (point 3 in my post) and I have only one Filter attached (point 5). Where should I check for such frameworks? I'll attache web.xml to my post

Comment: Well, run a debugger and look who's in turn redirecting/forwarding that login page to "first view I see after successful login" and fix it over there.

Comment: The last line in debug is `response.getWriter().printf(FACES_REDIRECT_XML, s);` in my Filter. And then I can see in firebug HTTP POST 302 and HTTP GET 200 with that weird "first view I see after successful login"

Comment: Yes, I know. The redirect tells the webbrowser to go to `/somecontext/login.xhtml` (that's the 302) and then webbrowser goes to `/somecontext/login.xhtml` (that's the 200) and then retrieves the wrong content back. You need to track the code logic behind the request on `/somecontext/login.xhtml`.

Comment: But I still have no idea where should I set the breakpoint? I believe that `FacesServlet` do process this request (Could I somehow track(debug) `FacesServlet`'s activity?). Or should I attach some additional `Filter` or something (but I have already one mapped on `*.xhtml`)? If I directly go to `/somecontext/login.xhtml` in browser - it works fine.

Comment: @BalusC OMG! In my `Filter` there was parasitic `if` operator that implements non-AJAX redirect too! Many thanks for Your time and attention! And sorry for wasting it! =)

Comment: I think you can tell browser to REDIRECT(302) or GET page in single response, if both are sent browser will not behave as expected above.