# Injecting Beans in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2, dependency-injection, javabeans, cdi

I have a Session scoped bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable{
```

I inyect the object in one Filter...

```
public class FiltroSeguridad implements Filter{

@Inject
private SessionBean sessionBean;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  sessionBean.setRutaRedirect(httpRequest.getRequestURI());
}
}
```

But, I inyect SessionBean in the next interaction...

```
@Model
public class CuentaUsuarioWebBean implements Serializable{
 @Inject
 private SessionBean sessionBean;

public void loginUsuario() throws IOException{
   sessionBean.getRutaRedirect();
}

}
```

But the property `getRutaRedirect()` returns null

I change the import by CDI annotations it still doesn't work (`javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`), same with JSF annotation (`javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` and `@ManagedProperty`).

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my English!

Comment: This works only if you have a `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` file (which a bit sane IDE would already autogenerate when you choose the CDI facet and/or which is already mentioned in a bit sane CDI tutorial, if you've read a tutorial). Do you have this file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't mix annotations from those two packages you're using `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` for JSF, and `import javax.inject.Named` for CDI. Both reflect different injection mechanisms and cannot be mixed on the same bean. You have to pick both annotations(for Injection and Bean Scoping) from the same package. Use the following sets from their corresponding packages

For CDI-based bean definitions

```
javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped //for bean scoping
javax.inject.Named //for bean declaration
javax.inject.Inject //for injection
```

For JSF-based bean definitions

```
javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped //for bean scoping
javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean //for bean declaration
javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty //for bean injection
```

EDIT: Now I understand your requirements better, use the following construct to inject a JSF managed bean

```
 @ManagedProperty(value="#{yourBeanName}")
 SessionBean yourSessionBean;
```

Also note that within JSF, you can inject only beans of a wider scope than their targets e.g. you can inject a `@SessionScoped` bean into a `@RequestScoped` bean and not the other way around

But since JSF managed beans are deprecated, better to use the CDI managed ones. In that case you **can** inject shorter scoped beans in wider scoped ones

Comment: Hello, I try that. But dont works. I import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped with javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean. I import import javax.inject.Named with javax.inject.Named but the bean dont change the property when I set a value. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanPabloGómezUribe, you can't use `@Inject` for a JSF bean. `@inject` is only applicable to beans within the context of CDI. For beans under JSF, use `@ManagedProperty`. See updated answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I prove with JSF-Based bean definitions and try inject the bean SessionBean with @ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}"), but this is injected as null (the bean have set and get). And use de CDI-Based and have the initial problem. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanPabloGómezUribe what's your environment(JSF version and App server)?

Comment: Hi, JSF 2.0 and GlassFish 3.1

Answer (score 5):

Forget about managed beans. It won't work with a Filter that way. If you insist on using it then do it properly by follow the answer provided here:

[How implement a login filter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf)

Now regarding CDI, if you problem is that a specific value is null and you have verified this by actually getting a NPE or so (Since for example Eclipse debugger sometimes get's it wrong). Then double check that you used correct SessionScoped like described by kolossus and also check what BalusC said (beans.xml).

A good way to see if CDI is working is to ask the manager for the bean. Put this debug code somewhere and try it:

```
@Inject
BeanManager manager;

@PostConstruct
private void test() {
    Bean<?> bean = (Bean) manager.resolve(manager.getBeans("ANY_NAMED_BEAN_EL_NAME"));
        System.out.println(bean);

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks fir reply. I try with that [How implement a login filter in JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf).

Comment: If you want to. I much prefer CDI myself.

Comment: I agree with @KarlKildén.. why using JSF managed beans if we have CDI beans