# Login system with Java EE

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, login-system

I´m trying to make a simple login system with Java EE (Hibernate, Glassfish, JSF). I am done with the handling of user id data i.e the users can enter username and password and it checks with the database and logs them in if its correct. But, I want to include certain pages that only logged in members can see. How can I keep track if a member is logged in ? and how can I get the information of that specific user?

Ex: I login and want to change my password, so I go to a page with my user details and enters a new password. How can I manage this serverside ?

Do I use a servlet? Cookies? Sessions? I´m lost (a)

I hope my question is clear, and would really appreciate some help.
Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)

Comment: Maybe this would be also usefull: [How implement a login filter in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to duplicate a feature that Java EE & GlassFish already supports.

Check out the Java EE Tutorial on how to do this with the JDBC Realm:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/jdbc-realm-and-form-based

Answer (score 2):

In Java EE 6 you can use the JASPIC api to create and register authentication modules. There are a number of authentication modules available for reuse.

You then configure constraints for URL patterns in web.xml for which a user has to be logged-in and for which one or more roles are required.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your user information in as a `SessionAttribute`, and the on the other pages chek if the session has a user or not.
If it has then the page loads correctly, if not you can redirect to the login screen.

The other question (the password change):
you can create a page for this with a form. You ask the user for his/her old password, and the new password twice.
Then on submit check the old password (as at login), check the new password (if you hyave any criteriy about that. ie: length, character types), chek if the two new passwords are the same.
If so then update your DB and login your user with the new password.