# Access to any page without going through the login page

Tags: jsf, filter, java-ee-6

I am developing a web application using Java/J2EE and JSF. My application contains a several pages with a login page where the user enters his login and password. My problem is when i enter the url of any page i can access to it without going through the login page. How to prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8480241/1362049

Comment: What configuration do you have for Java EE security in your web.xml file? You may wish to revisit the Security Roles guide from Sun whilst combing through your configuration: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncav.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How implement a login filter in JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf)

Answer (score -1):

The answer u've suggested to me didn't work for me. I was obliged to override the init() method as this:

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String urls = filterConfig.getInitParameter("restrictedPages");
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");
        ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            urlList.add(token.nextToken());
        }
    }
```

And i've added this lines in the web. xml

```
   <init-param>
                <param-name>restrictedPages</param-name>
                <param-value>/login.jsp</param-value>
            </init-param>
```

And my doFilter method is:

```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);     
            if (session == null || session.getAttribute("idCustomer") == null) {
                response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
    }
```