# Authentication filter not working, app seems to be redirecting from http://192.35.36.178:8042/ to http:172.36.98.658//8042/

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I am trying to restrict an user to access any pages if user if not authorized based the code found in [How implement a login filter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf/8480241#8480241)

I am using jsf 2.2 and primefaces. Below are my code:

**My filter**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns = { "*.xhtml" })
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {


            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            String user = (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("username")
                    .toString() : null;
            
            String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/ldapLogin.xhtml";
            boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(loginURL);
            boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(
                    request.getContextPath()
                            + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);
            if (user != null || loginRequest) 
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()
                        + "/ldapLogin.xhtml");
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Here my control is coming into the else condition when my session is not validated or If i am trying to access a page directly but Unable to redirect to **ldapLogin.xhtml**

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
    <param-value>en</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/applicationContext-dao.xml,
             /WEB-INF/springLdap-security.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/taglibs/acegijsf.taglib.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>ldapLogin.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

**LoginLdap.java**

```
public String ldapLoginAuthentcator() {
        if (contact != null) {
            HttpSession session = FilterUtil.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", user.getName());
            return "success";
        } else {
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"Invalid Login!", "Please TryAgain!"));
            return "login";
        }
```

Finally **FilterUtil.java**

```
public class FilterUtil {
 
      public static HttpSession getSession() {
   return(HttpSession)FacesContextgetCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
      }
```

}

I dont know what is the problem but when I trying to access a page and even if I am authorized or my session is not validated but still I can access the page. Any help would be appropriated. All pages are currently in same root path as a public not placed in web-inf folder.

UPDATE:

When I tried to access a page directly without a valid session, for example if I am trying to access `http://192.35.36.178:8042/SOW/start` and its coming to my filtering and successfully filtering but redirection is not happening , When I tried to check it with firebug its redirecting to some different planet. Its actually redirecting to

```
 "http:172.36.98.658//8042/SOW/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bootstrap"
```

with status **302 Found** instead of redrecting to
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/ldapLogin.xhtml")
as well as when i tried to check the **contextPath**  its showing **/sow**

Comment: @Makky thanks for your prompt response, actually i am a newbie in jsf , I have worked on struts2 but for the project requirement We need to implement this security. However instead of moving to PhaseListener  I would also like to know what is the problem with this filter and why it is not getting redirected to login.xhtml when user is not a valid user? as well as if you have some working code for PhaseListener then i would like to give it a try.

Comment: okay... you mean this filter would not work for ajax calls right, then please share me some working code.. thanx in advance

Comment: Can you confirm that the redirect request (a 302) is actually coming back to the browser and that the appropriate URL is being requested?

Answer (score 1):

i'll show you the way how i do it without using Filter or PhaseListener.

the best way if you use Templating, then put this line in the body of your template, OR (if no templates) in every page you want to restrict access:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{yourBean.checkPermissions}"/>
```

In A template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css"/>    
    <title>${pageTitle}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="${metaKeywords}" />
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="${metaDescription}" />
</h:head>

<body>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{yourBean.checkPermissions}"/>
...
```

in your Bean add the listener Method like this:

```
    public void checkPermissions(ComponentSystemEvent event) {

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)(fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false)); 
        String cid = (String) httpSession.getAttribute(AttributeName.ADMINISTRATOR_CLIENT_LOGIN_ID);
        if( cid == null){
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            handler.performNavigation(this.navi.getClientLogin().getLink());
            return;
        }
        ....
        ....
    }
```

**UPDATE:** a working example using Filter(i tested it Using JSF2.2 Mojarra 2.2, Tomcat 7):

edit/add/ this in your **web.xml**:

```
....
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


....
```

and here is a Sample Filter Impl.:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns = { "*.xhtml" })
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            System.out.println("doFilter ...");
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            String user = (session != null) ? (String)session.getAttribute("username") : null;
            String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/ldapLogin.xhtml";
            boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(loginURL);
            boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath()+ ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);
            if (user != null || loginRequest) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/ldapLogin.xhtml");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //      
    }
}
```

Comment: `<f:viewAction/>` is preferable in JSF2.2

Comment: Whilst that may work, this is *not* the recommended approach. A filter is. It's namely able to cover non-JSF requests.

Comment: @kolossus, thanks, thats correct what you suggest, as i'v copied it from an old Project, i was focused on the idea not on the Details.

Comment: @BalusC: first of all, i have to thankyou for all your amazing Posts on SO. Now to my Answer, that will work perfectly (sure only JSF), and i recommend using this over Filter due to so such issues like in the Question above. no need to handle all requests over all pages where no restriction is needed, and no problems with redirects ...etc, no need to check if response.isCommitted() or not ...etc.

Comment: @Rami.Q thanks for your suggestion... but i am here for how to resolve my problem, do u have any idea why its not redirecting to loginpage when i am trying to access directly.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: i updated my Answer and showed you a working example with Filter using your Code!

Comment: @Rami.Q If you check my question I have already done the same thing as you suggested ,but its not happening, I am still able to access page directly.

Comment: @BalusC when I am directly accessing a page filter is unable to redirect becasuse of context resource path i.e. 'http://localhost:8042/SOW/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development' , instead of redirecting condition its coming to chain.doFilter() statement. Please do your feedback.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk, you have systax errors in your code, and you miss the destroy method which must be implemented, i don't know how you able to run your project while you have errors!

Comment: @Rami.Q...which syntax error you are talking about... i did'nt find any, but if you are saying so please let me know...

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk:  if (user != null || loginRequest) 
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }, where is your opening bracket {? where is the destroy method? ...etc.

Comment: @Rami.Q.. I request you to check it before comment and by the way if (user != null || loginRequest) 
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {... here you can clearly see i am properly opening and closing the braces.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk; i mean for the if {} not for else statement: if (user != null || loginRequest) here you have to open it because you close it before else. just compare your if + else statement with mine in the answer, you will see the difference!