# Redirect from a Servlet filter, when an AJAX request is made

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, servlet-filters

The filter which is supposed to perform a redirect :

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "TestFilter", urlPatterns = {"/WEB-INF/jaas/*"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD})
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    public TestFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Home.xhtml");
        //chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    //...
}
```

There is only one XHTML file in the location which is mapped to the URL pattern.

The managed bean forwarding to the above filter.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestBean() {}

    public void action() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        context.dispatch("/WEB-INF/jaas/jaas.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Finally the `action()` method is bound to a `<p:commandButton>`.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{testBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

The said filter redirects to the said resource only when `ajax` associated with the `<p:commandButton>` is set to `false` as shown above.

In case of an Ajaxical request, the redirect which is supposed to be performed by the filter does not happen (no error).

Is it feasible to perform a redirect, when an Ajaxical request is sent to a filter in the above way?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but don't you just need to make an ajax redirect like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779489/servlet-filter-with-jsf ? BalusC has a variant in a post somewhere

Comment: I saw the duplicate question about a year ago but the memory got completely flushed out in the meantime.