# How to store application parameters in JSF/EJB application?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, architecture

There're a lot of parameters which I need to maintain while I perform developing/debugging in my JSF/EJB application:

- scheduler running or not
- can emails be sent or not
- can sms be sent or not
- [WebFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf) turned on or off, etc..

What is the best practice to maintain all these parameters? Make Java properties file as described here [Java Properties file examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) or there's better approach?

I need to define these parameters in a single place, and get access to them from JSF and EJB projects as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things you need to consider before you can choose the best alternative.
A properties file would be a good practice if these parameters are very rarely changed and are also user independent. 
You could also implement a singleton EJB that caches these values.
If these parameters you mention are user dependent or change often it would be better if you include them as user properties, or role properties. (Following an RBAC approach)