# How to access @SessionScoped beans from @WebFilter

Tags: cdi, servlet-filters, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am working on an AuthenticationFilter to redirect the user when he's not logged in. I am using TomEE 7.0.0-M2, so with Java-EE7 support.

AuthenticationFilter

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST})
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

@Inject
private LoginBean loginBean;
...
```

LoginBean

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
```

The problem is that the injected LoginBean is not the instance from the login.xhtml. So i can not verify if the user is successfully logged in.

The LoginBean is not in the session attributes, but i found the right loginBean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F1Cw.png), but i have no idea how i can access it. But it looks like that the bean is in CDI but how can i access it from the WebFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't have an answer but an another solution that BalusC mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf):

When the user is successfully logged i just add the loginBean manually to the sessionMap

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("loginBean", this);
```

In the WebFilter i access the loginBean with

```
session.getAttribute("loginBean")
```

Is this a good solution? I mean.. sounds like a workaround.