# Avoid user copy and paste url without have logged id

Tags: jsf, primefaces, faces-config

**What I want to avoid is that the user access to a .xhtml throu url without have logged in**

My Application is being develope in JSF and Primefaces. I have read about navegation-rule, but I have not reach my goal

--this is the url of the first page
http://localhost:8089/Prueba-war/index.xhtml

--this is the next page after log in
http://localhost:8089/Prueba-war/faces/main.xhtml

What I want is to avoid user to copy and paste the url of the main page

Comment: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf