# Primefaces 6.1 missing look and feel in Weblogic12.2.1

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, weblogic12c

We have an application that was originally started using Glassfish 4.0 using JSF2.2 and Primefaces 6.1 and everything worked exactly as we intended it to until it was decided that we would be moving to Weblogic 12.2.1.2. Since the application has been moved all of the navigation, EJBs, etc all work just as before but the primefaces UI is completely out of whack. None of the styling is there anymore even after making sure the resources directory was defined properly in the web.xml. I know this is a pretty vague question but I was hoping that someone had experienced a similar problem and found a solution.

Comment: What did you **debug**. If the PF components look bad it is a css related thing. 404's? security filters?  considering an edit by BalusC in a related topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf I suspect something in this direction. But that should be easy to debug by you...

Comment: That's the main problem there are no errors anywhere to debug but like you said it does look like the CSS is not being loaded as it should, just haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: Checking if the css files are not loaded is easy... Network tab should contain 404's then (or other 'errors')

Comment: After a little more digging I have found a log message that could be the culprit. "<jsf.config.listener.version> <Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8-17 ( 20160803-1954 unable to get svn info) for context '/XXX'>" If this is the problem I'm unsure as to why it happens on Weblogic 12.2.1 and not on glassfish 4.x.

Comment: I doubt it is the reason. It is a jsf issue, then plain jsf would not work either.

Comment: So it seems that then using the Weblogic 12.2.1.3 developer installation if you use an IP instead of localhost when configuring the domain this problem arises, weird. Tried a domain both ways several times and each time I use an IP instead of localhost when configuring this problem comes up so localhost it is. Thanks for the input.