# How to avoid to go back after click on back button of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using jsp and jquery.

After logging in, the home page is displayed, but when I click on the back button of browser, it show me log in page again.

When I click on the back button, I want it to redirect to the home page, like GMail does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)

Comment: I try this, but its not working in spring.

Comment: It's not only disabling the browser cache, but also checking if the user is logged in. Disabling the browser cache only makes sure that the back button will hit the server instead of the browser cache. You still need to check if the user is logged in when a restricted resource is requested.

Comment: I am checking user is log in or not in the controller for login.do request.When I click on back button first time after log in, it show login.jsp page again(Its showing me page which is in cache), but second time when I click on back button request redirected to home.jsp through controller.

Comment: Then you either didn't clear your browser cache after implementing the filter or mapped the filter on the wrong URL pattern (it has to cover URLs which should not be cached, perhaps you need `*.do` instead of `*.jsp`).

Comment: 1) <filter>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.xyz.LoginController</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: 2) so i need to implement Filter interface. eg: LoginController implements Filter, and LoginController have method @RequestMappint("/login.do") public ModelAndView login(req, res){}. But login.do request does come here.

Comment: Uh uh, a Filter is not part of Spring MVC API, it's part of standard Servlet API. I suggest to go through some basic Servlet tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for ur support. But, how to implement the same specifically in Spring MVC framework.

Comment: Just implement it the documented way. It works as good together with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply check if someone is logged in at the login page, and if so redirect to the homepage. No magic necessary here.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I am doing same.I am using spring framework. when I am clicking on back button then request for login page is not coming into controller(where i am retun modelandview for login page)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to check whether a user is login or not in login page. If user is login then redirect him/her to your desired page, otherwise login him.

Comment: pls, check above comment for hoppa.