# Redirect page to custom page instead of default saying "web page has expired" upon using back/forward button

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am busy with a site which has only one page, accessible only after logging in: `home.jsp`. Once user is logged in with a valid session, if he presses the back button on the browser then he should be redirected to `login.jsp` and again if he presses the browser's forward button. He should not be able to get to `home.jsp` without logging in. So after doing some searches, I've implemented:

```
<%
response.setHeader ( "Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");

response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");

response.setDateHeader ( "Expires", 0)
%>
```

On the `home.jsp` page and upon pressing the forward button, it's saying web page has expired, but what I'm looking for is my cutom page, something like `sessionExpired.jsp` saying log in again...

Please help me out with how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. So, everytime when the enduser sends a (successful) POST request, send a **redirect** to the target page instead of a forward. This way the back button will point to the redirected GET request instead of the initial POST request.

E.g. in your `doPost()` method handling the login:

```java
User user = userService.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/home.jsp");
}
```

And in your `doPost()` method handling the logout:

```java
request.getSession().invalidate();
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
```

Do not forget to implement a no-cache filter as instructed in [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout/4194251#4194251), otherwise the browser might still present the previously visited secured page from its cache. It is **not** correct to set these response headers in every single JSP via the *Scriptlets* way as visible in your code snippet.

Comment: @BalusC-- Thanks, Can I use the same logic with `RequestDispacther` method also in which I'll be going to target via rdObj.forward(request,response)---RequestDispacther object.???

Comment: This does not send a redirect. It sends a forward. Do you understand the difference?