# After logout, when click on back button the secured last visited page appears due to cache issue in october cms. How to prevent this?

Tags: browser-cache, logout, cache-control, octobercms

Hi I am new to ocotber cms. I have observed that after I logout(page redirects to home page), when I press back button the page redirects to the last visited secured page.

However when I click on any of the link on that page, the page refreshes and redirect again to home page.

I don't want secured page to be seen again after logout. How to achieve this.

I have seen a similar query - [after logout click on back button cache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330336/after-logout-click-on-back-button-cache-issue)
but the query was asked 6 years ago and there is lots of information to grasp.

I have a website with https protocol and I use user plugin.

Is there a way in october cms to stop viewing secured page after logout. Or are there some steps I missed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. I guess this thread can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button . Not sure whether OctoberCMS provides this feature inbuilt or not however OctoberCMS is flexible enough if you want to customize the things as per your needs in your themes. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Being a novice I am not sure how much I can customize. I tried to find answers on net, I found that to control cache in php, we need  to include header(cache-control:..), I am not sure how to use it. Can you please explain this.

Comment: You can get slack support of OctoberCMS .. https://octobercms.slack.com/