# I am using struts freamwork, after log out when i pressed browser back button it is going to last opened page. How to send it to log in page?

Tags: java, struts

I am using struts framework, after log out when i pressed browser back button it is going to last opened page. How to send it to log in page?

Actually i want solution in java not in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must be having a security filter to intercept all incoming requests. If not you need to have one to authenticate user session. Here on failure you can forward to login page.

Also check if the page is rendered from browser cache. If so you can set no-cache in the header of the JSP.

```
<%
   response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
   response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
   response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
%>
```

Comment: you will have to do this in each and every jsp, considering your application has hundreds of jsp this becomes a hard to keep track of.

Comment: my log in page and log out page is same ,i put that code on log in page but not working

Comment: You can also use the filter to put that on all the responses.

Answer (score -1):

If you have invalidated (`session.invalidate();`) your session through logout, just in action control you forward your request to the jsp page you want. Once session is broken if you press back it won't go to the same page I think.

Comment: Can you please try to form normal sentences and words? You are writing in fasttalk/SMS/chat style which is hard to understand for anyone whose native tongue is not English. Thank you.