# Calling a servlet /logout from a template.xhtml

Tags: jsf, web-applications, primefaces

I would like to call a servlet /logout from a templateHeader.xhtml which is located in the folder templates as followed:

```html
webapp
 |-- form
 |    |-- form.xhtml
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- templates
 |    |    |-- template.xhtml
 |    |    |-- templateFooter.xhtml
 |    |    |-- templateHeader.xhtml
 |-- resources
 |-- admin.xhtml
 |-- login.xhtml
 :
```

The problem is that I don't know how to call the servet because the path to servlet is not the same depending on the page you are on. I am looking for an equivalent of #{request.contextPath}/myPage but for the servlet. And just by curiosity, if I wanted to call a method myMethod() from a bean Login, how would I do?

I have followed this [Kill session and redirect to login page on click of logout button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707225/kill-session-and-redirect-to-login-page-on-click-of-logout-button) but I think I am using it wrong. Note that I have also tried to add  *method="post"* to the menuitem. Note also that the first menuitem of the code below is working.

templateHeader.xhtml

```html
<ui:composition 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" size="50">
  <h:form> 
   <p:menubar>
    <p:menuitem value="Satisfact'IT" url="#{request.contextPath}/admin.xhtml" icon="fa fa-home" />
    <p:menuitem value="Quitter" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" icon="fa fa-sign-out"/>
   </p:menubar>
  </h:form>
 </p:layoutUnit>
</ui:composition>
```

template.xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >    
    <h:head>
 </h:head>
    <h:body>
  <p:layout fullPage="true" >   
      <ui:insert name="header" >
          <ui:include src="commonHeader.xhtml" />
      </ui:insert>
        
      <ui:insert name="footer" >
          <ui:include src="commonFooter.xhtml" />
      </ui:insert>
  </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And finally the logout servlet

```js
@WebServlet("/logout")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I think you want to do.

Create a normal JSF controller (e.g LogoutController) method like...

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Change your menu item to..

```
<p:menuitem value="Quitter" action="${logoutController.logout}" icon="fa fa-sign-out"/>
```