# session does not invalidates

Tags: java, servlet-filters, httpsession

I'm trying to write a filter, which checks if user is logged in, and in case is not redirect him to login page. previously I had filter which actually did nothing -_-  here it is, and with this filter everythig works ok, and session invalidates:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("UserName") == null) { 
        String command = request.getParameter("command");

        request.setAttribute("command", "login");
        // String page = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getProperty(
        // ConfigurationManager.LOGIN_PAGE_PATH);

    } else {
        String username = (String) session.getAttribute("UserName");
        UserRole role;
        try {
            role = UserDAOImpl.getUserRole(username);
            session.setAttribute("role", role);
        } catch (DAOTechnicException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (DAOLogicException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res); 
}
```

and when I invalidate session then it goes to (if session == null) block, and everything is ok.

but now I have another filter, here it is :

```
public class UserCheckFilter implements Filter {

    static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest) request);
        }

        public String getParameter(String paramName) {
            String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
            if(value!=null){
                if (value.equals("login")) {
                    return value;
                }

                HttpSession session = super.getSession();
                if (session == null || session.getAttribute("UserName") == null) {
                    value = "login";
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if user logged in and if not redirects to login page
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("UserName") == null) {
            if(request.getParameter("command")!=null){
                String command = request.getParameter("command");
                if(!command.equals("login")){
                    FilteredRequest filtrequest = new FilteredRequest(request);
                    String filteredvalue = filtrequest.getParameter("command");
                    chain.doFilter(filtrequest, res);
                }else{
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            }else{
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        } else {
            String username = (String) session.getAttribute("UserName");
            UserRole role;
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            try {
                role = UserDAOImpl.getUserRole(username);
                session.setAttribute("role", role);

            } catch (DAOTechnicException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (DAOLogicException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

in which I wrap getParameter method and check if not logged in user is trying to go to user or admin pages. But when I invalidate session, it does not invalidates, i.e. all parameters are staying the same, and then in the filter where it checks if session != null, it's not null, and in line session.setAttribute("role", role); I get exception **"session is already invalidated"**

here's the method where i invalidate session :

```
    if(request.getSession(false)!=null){
        request.getSession().invalidate();
    }
    String page = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getProperty(
                ConfigurationManager.LOGIN_PAGE_PATH);
    return page;
```

and in servlet U use

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(page);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and btw such things with invalidating session occurs only with second filter

p.s. sorry for probably stupid question, but I really don't know what's wrong, 
so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14562188/738746 very clearly explains when and what exactly you should do to achieve what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you're always calling chain.doFilter().

Per Oracle's docs...

> A typical implementation of this method would follow the following
>   pattern:-
>
> 1. Examine the request
> 2. Optionally wrap the request object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for input filtering
> 3. Optionally wrap the response object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for output filtering
> 4. a) **Either** invoke the next entity in the chain using the FilterChain object (chain.doFilter()),
> 5. b) **or** not pass on the request/response pair to the next entity in the filter chain to block the request processing
> 6. Directly set headers on the response after invocation of the next entity in the filter chain.

In step 4, you probably want to do (b) - that is, instead of passing the request to the next filter in the chain, return the result to the user.  I mean, it's an invalid session, so why bother trying to perform additional processing?