# Preventing JSP from caching

Tags: java, jsp, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1); 
%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="com.services.*" import="java.util.*"
    import="java.text.*"%>
<jsp:include page="top.jsp"></jsp:include>

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="login-box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="getcontacts();deleteContact();">    
</html>
```

I'm trying to prevent my web application from caching, I inserted the following piece   of code:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); 
%>
```

but it's still caching, when i logout and i press back it still comes back to the last session.any hlep plz. should i insert something else ??

Comment: See also - [Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4194207/1037210)

Comment: -1 is wrong, 0 is correct.