# How to Prevent user from going back to the previous jsp pages after logout action in struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

For me, it looks like a situation where i have to reset the browser cache or
something like that. I googled a lot about that and i find that delete cache
is impossible, but i find some javascript scripts, or use
`response.setHeaders` but none of that worked for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633221/1654265

Answer (score 0):

**unset** and **destroy**  the **session variables** and **expire** the cookies if stored any in the logout script

Comment: i already did it, but browsers back button show previous jsp pages and i want to prevent them.

Comment: you need to instruct the browser to not cache those pages

Comment: if i do that end user can't use forward and back button during run the application , i only want he restrict for back button or to view last navigate pages after logout like in Facebook or banking sites.