# Is it necessary to use SessionMap in struts2?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

```
HttpSession session;
session=request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

i m working on struts2 and hibernate framework.i have written this code in Logoutaction class but on pressing the back button in browser,its taking me to the old profile,which shouldn't happen after invalidating the session.So,should i use SessionMap or Map instead of HttpSession to invalidate the session??
i have searched for this but all i could find was the use of map and SessionMap.

Comment: How it's related to the title?

Comment: The session map *has* an invalidate method that works; the issue is almost certainly caching, not the session handling.

Comment: yeah.. but then this shouldn't be happening on pressing the back button.

Comment: It would if you're doing caching wrong.

Comment: @Nidhi: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633221/1654265

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to logout from the session:

```
package simple;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.opensymphony.webwork.ServletActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork.ActionSupport;

public class LogoutAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() throws Exception { 
     Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.remove("logined"); 
session.remove("context");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

}

Comment: What are `logined` and `context`?

Comment: i wrote your code but the problem of going back to the last opened profile still persists..

Comment: "logined" and "context" are sesseion variables,they are just an example

Comment: @Nidhi Because your page is cached.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of back button is that the browser is showing the cached page. To prevent browser caching,

you need to put following in header of your page.

> "Cache-control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
>   "Pragma", "no-cache"
>   "Expires", "-1"
>   "Vary", "*"

You can do it either using [interceptor](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/Interceptors/CachingHeadersInterceptor.java) or putting code in action or [jsp](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/WebContent/viewServices.jsp) page.

[Removing Session code](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/com.action.common/LogoutAction.java) is to remove session only, it can not remove cache. But server side for every action you can check session by making [interceptor](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/Interceptors/AuthorizationInterceptor.java) and prevent user from performing action if session is destroyed.

It is **not necessary** to use map. But struts2 provide `ServletAware` interface to work with session. It is your choice to go with struts2 or not.