# How to skip the back page in jsp after user has logged in?

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, struts2

I have developed a Website using jsp, java and struts2. When I login using the credentials in my website. I am logged in and redirected to new page. But when I press back button I am redirected to login page. I want to skip the login page when I press back button.

Similarly I want the same to do when I logout from the page.

How can I do this? Any other solution is fine as well.

Thanks.

Comment: If the previous page was a login page and you press the back button, what should it display if not the login page?

Comment: It can remain in the same page that was displayed after login

Comment: You can have the login page redirect to the index page if the user's session exists.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633221/1654265