# Session is not working properly after sendRedirect() in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session

The code of session is not working properly. I copied a link and after logout when I tried to access that link than it was working without asking a login.

Here is the code of my login page on which I have created session:

```
String user_name=request.getParameter("user_name");        
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
session.setAttribute("user_name", user_name);
session.setAttribute("pass",pass);
```

Here is the code of that page on which I have transferred my session:

```
 String user_name = (String)session.getAttribute("user_name");
```

Here is the code of logout page:

```
session.setAttribute("user_name", null);
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
response.addHeader("cache-control","no-cache");
```

Comment: How do u check whether someone is logged on? (don't store passwords in sessions.. :-) )

Comment: `String user_name = (String)session.getAttribute("user_name"); `
`user_name` will be null while redirecting back to login page after logout. you can check it by `sysout`

Comment: A session doesn't check whether you're logged in or not. It simply stores attributes for a given user (authenticated or not). It's your job to check if a user is authenticated before accessing a restricted resource.

Comment: Hey Pravin, yes user name will be null after logout, but it is redirecting back to home page if I press back button after logout.

Comment: Hey JB, I am also checking for authentication and that is not my problem. Here is the code for the authentication 
if(user_name!=null && pass!=null){
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:epm","root","root");
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where user_name =? and pass =?");   
    pst.setString(1, user_name);
    pst.setString(2, pass); 
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){ 
       }else{      
     }
}

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Every time a request comes in to a restricted resource, you must check that the user is authenticated. Not just at login time. The session doesn't do that for you. The session is just a mechanism to associate state to a user. You could for example add a flag "isAuthenticated" to the session. But you need to check that flag every time it's needed.

Comment: Hello DarkBee,
Thanks for your suggestion but again I am facing same problem after removing password from session.

Comment: Okay Nizet,
Now I understand what you want to say. Thanks for your help. I have to initialize isAuthenticated flag at the time of login and that that flag is used on every page. Right?

Comment: What happens when you use the three response headers as given by BalusC ? at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout

Comment: Hello rickz,
Actually i am looking for a solution in jsp, I am not using servlet. But, thanks it will help any other time.

Comment: Yes, please put the three header lines in your JSP.

Comment: But, actually I do not want to include servlet.

Comment: @Rajat you need to check that isAuthenticated is true every time the user must be authenticated to access the page. This should be done in a ServletFilter, once and for all. Not in each individual page. Using only JSPs is awful design. Use the MVC principle, and use the JSP as a view component only. JSPs should not contain any Java code. Only custom tags and the JSP EL.

Comment: You don't need a Servlet. Just use the three header lines in your JSP.

Comment: I know it is a sin. But just use a JSP for a test.

Comment: @rickz I used the code, but it is showing an error that void is not a return type of doFilter method.

Comment: All I suggested was a simple test. Just the three response header lines insert into your two JSPs.  But, maybe JB Nizet is right.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is important the `sendRedirect()` should be the last command to response.

```
response.addHeader("cache-control","no-cache");
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

In the `index.jsp`, if it's a protected resource, you should redirect to a login page if not a valid `user_name` in session.

```
String user_name = (String)session.getAttribute("user_name"); 
if (user_name == null) response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

Comment: hello Roman,
Thanks for this information and yes I always write sendRedirect() as last command to response.