# How do I create logout page in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I have a logout page with these codes written in it.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if(session != null)
  session.invalidate();
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

However after clicking the log out button and after redirecting to index.jsp, I can still access the previously visited links using the back button of the browser. How do I make my way around with this? That after I have logged out, I will always be redirected into the index.jsp (my login page) unless I log in again? Help?

Comment: This might be [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(session != null)
    {
        session.setAttribute("loginBean", null);
        session.invalidate();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

Answer (score -1):

On click to browser button,the page would have been served from cache,you can check it by Network tab in your browser(`F12 in chrome`).

On server side,you should do below things.

1.you can check the session at a common point (let say it be a `filter` or any `servlet controller`(other than for login request)). if session is available you allow to proceed,and if not redirect user to login page.

2.On logout, as you are doing already `session.invalidate()`

3.Also i would suggest, to add below headers to `HttpServletResponse` object on logout.

```
    Cache-Control,Pragma,No Cache,Expire

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```