# JSP sessions user authentication

Tags: validation, jsp, session

I am created a JSP web application,and in which I use sessions for user authentication. My problem is,I invalidate all sessions in logout.jsp,But after execute logout If Iam click on the back button on browser I can easily enters to the previous page.But I already checked the sessions in all pages. How to solve this

Comment: Without any code we can not see where the problem is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout