# How to prevent the user to access the history after logout the application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a SpringMVC application I need to make a logout page. I make the page but when I click the back button on the browser I can see the user data.

How can I prevent the user to access the history after logout the application.   Please tell me a solution without using Spring-security.

I am using the following handler method for logout the application.

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return "index";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: clear browser history on clicking the logout button, no?

Comment: USe Login filter to validate each request.

Comment: @khAn how can we do that in Springmvc ... i am newbie to springmvc

Comment: @dhS i cant give full working example but my answer might help you, please search on google for any tutorials. it would be a good practice.

Comment: See some examples here https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=handlerinterceptoradapter%20spring%203%20example

Comment: @khAn this would help me for sure ... but for now the other answer worked .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add below line at top of your jsp page to not to store history or cache

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");//HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop user to go back to previous page history

You can use javascript

```
window.history.forward();<br>
function noBack(){<br>
window.history.forward();
}
```

But this is not the best approach because of various numerous reasons.

There are many other solutions
1. Invalidate the session
2. Clear the cache

[See this](https://coderanch.com/t/491725/JSP/java/prevent-user-browse-previous-page) and [also this already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)

Comment: I don't have to use javascript in this application. but this is a good solution for other applications thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Spring frame works then use interceptor to avoid such behavior of your application.

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

}

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
    }
}
```

`