# Java dynamic web application - back button doesn't work in browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Im new to java web application. okay question is, I have application with multiple tabs. If I click gallery tab from being in home page, it goes to gallery page and if I click back button of browser it doesn't go to home page. Im using servlet, JSP. What could be the reason? Pls help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)

Answer (score 0):

Each browser maintains browsing history. While you use back or forward options it comes through history and request send to server.

Comment: I know boss.. My question why for my application its not working. whether do i need to do any history setting in my app?

Comment: What the issue. Why do need control client side?

Comment: issue is forward and back buttons are not working but Other website's are working.. Why only my app's?

Comment: Is it mobile application?