# Back Button Issue after login, Confirm Form Resubmission Error Showing

Tags: java

I'm working on prevent back button after login,. i'm including this code in jsp page.

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
    if (session.getAttribute("userName") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
%>
```

but when i press back button following error is showing

Confirm Form Resubmission
This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)

Comment: Have a look at the [post-redirect-get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).