# Session Invalidation on logout button in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, redirect, session-variables, logout

After logout commands redirect to Login.html page. session invalidated correctly, but if pressing back button previous page opened(this page need valid session for open) and if i am reloading this page then this page sending redirect to login page. (this is very important that if i am pressing back button after logout, it should send redirect to login page)

```
<% 
  // session invalidate
  if (session!=null) {
    session.invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect("Login.html");
  }
 %>
```

Comment: <%
  if(session.getAttribute("session-uid") == null || session.getAttribute("session-uid").equals(""))
  {
    %><jsp:forward page="Login.html" /><%
  }
  else{
      if(session.getAttribute("session-uid").equals("User"))
      {
      }
      else{ %><jsp:forward page="Login.html" /><%  }

      }
%>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)