# After Logout I can click browser back button to go back to site

Tags: java, session, servlets, logout

I am working with Java Servlet and here is a method that I wrote, but it is not working:

```
    public static void noCache(HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    }
```

This method is called but not working and displaying previous page when browser back button is clicked after logout

Comment: Did you try `myServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();`?

Comment: I am calling as HttpSession session.invalidate();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)